# javac do not generate any Error or jar file in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, javac

I study hdfs, so I test simple MapReduce code that gets average of overall in JSON file.

Json form's sample is in [here(click me)](http://jmcauley.ucsd.edu/data/amazon/)

**GetAverage.java**

```
package some.package.path.here.bigdata;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.FloatWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

import org.json.*;

public class GetAverage extends Configured implements Tool {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
        int res = ToolRunner.run(new Configuration(), new GetAverage(), args);

        System.exit(res);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));

        Job job = Job.getInstance(getConf());
        job.setJarByClass(GetAverage.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        //Overall value type is float.
        job.setOutputValueClass(FloatWritable.class);

        job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.waitForCompletion(true);

        return 0;
    }

    public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, FloatWritable> {
        private Text asin_value = new Text();
        private FloatWritable overall_value = new FloatWritable();

        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            String asin;
            float overall;
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] tuple = line.split("\\n");

            try{
                for(int i=0; i<tuple.length; i++){
                    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(tuple[i]);
                    System.out.println(obj);
                    asin = obj.getString("asin");
                    overall = Float.parseFloat(obj.getString("overall"));

                    asin_value.set(asin);
                    overall_value.set(overall);

                    context.write(asin_value, overall_value);
                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, FloatWritable, Text, FloatWritable> {
        @Override
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<FloatWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            float sum = 0;
            int length = 0;
            for (FloatWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
                length++;
            }
            float average = sum / length;
            context.write(key, new FloatWritable(average));
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this, Code do not showing any message and generate any jar file.

I compile this java file with under command.

cat ./complie command

> javac -classpath /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.8.0.jar:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.8.0.jar:../org.json.jar -d getaverage_classes/ GetAverage.java

And my directory structure is...

```
~/test |- GetAverage.java
       |- compile_command
       |- getaverage_classes - some/package/path/here/bigdata |-GetAverage$Map.class
                                                              |- GetAverage$Reduce.class
                                                              |- GetAverage.class
```

Please answer my question anyone knows this problem. :)

Comment: `javac` doesn't produce jar files, it just compiles .java source code files to .class files. Use `jar` tool to create archives, or use a full-featured build tool like maven/gradle/etc.

Comment: Oh, I miss that command... too silly! Thank you for knowing that.

Comment: You should really be using Maven or Gradle, though, to manage external dependencies and produce JAR files... Also, Spark, Hive, or Pig can find averages of JSON files in less than 20 lines of code... So are you required to use MapReduce for some reason?

Comment: By the way, `line.split("\\n");` doesn't do anything... Your `value` String is already a single line with no newline characters. That's what `TextInputFormat` does

Comment: The reason why I use MapReduce is for assignment. :) And I trying without ‘line.split’. Thank you so much!